# Preferred way to carry a value across pages to use as route parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, model-binding

I want to have a select list that will list items from a table query for the user to select.
This is rendered with

```cs
 Options = _context.BranchAssignment
            .Where(a => a.ColleagueID == UserColleague)
            .IgnoreQueryFilters()
            .OrderBy(a => a.Branch.BranchNumber)
            .Select(a => 
             new SelectListItem
             {
                 Value = a.BranchID.ToString(),
                 Text = a.Branch.BranchName
             })                                    
             .ToList();
```

```html
<form id="assignedBranch" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <select asp-for="BranchSelect" asp-items="Model.Options" onchange="this.form.submit();"></select>
            </div>
        </form>
```

As you can see it is a very simple form. My current in-development solution should onFormSubmit, take the selected option, set it as a cookie value, and then I can set the selected option for the select list if the user navigates to another page.

I am still debugging issues with this and it has me wondering if there is a better solution. Ideally, I would want this select list written once and shown in _layout navbar but I believe you can't read from a view component (my last attempt) to get the selected value to use as a route parameter in the OnGet.

If you imagine user goes to Page A and select list selected item is Option 2 then via onGet I want to load webaddress.com/PageA/option2 as route will be set as option2

If they then go to Page B then the select list will render and remember their previous option of option2 so it will load webaddress.com/PageB/option2 and if they can change to e.g. option3 and after OnFormSubmit webaddress.com/PageB/option3 will load.

If I am going about this the wrong way I would be grateful for a push towards the preferred process.

Comment: I don't suggest you to use route to pass the value, It may cause some routing conflicts , you can just use cookie.

Comment: @XinranShen My question may have been unclear, but I don't intend to pass any values in the route, cookies were my likely option for passing values, but the route would be set in the onGet of the page based on the cookie value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use cookie to carry a value across pages instead of using route parameter.

I achieve it in two steps:

**Firstly**, add an `Onchange` event to `<select>`, when you choose an option, the `Onchange` event will set a cookie to save the value which you choose.

**Secondly**, when you load other pages, the `<select>` will read the cookie to show your previous selection.

Here is my code:

`DropDown List` in **_layout .cshtml**

```
<li>
    <select id="fruit" onchange="save(this.value)">
       <option value=0>apple</option>
       <option value=1>pear</option>
       <option value=2>watermelon</option>
       <option value=3>cherry</option>
     </select>
</li>
```

`JavaScript` in **_layout .cshtml**

```
<script>
         //....................set Cookie............
       var saveclass = null;

        function save(cookieValue)
        {
            var sel = document.getElementById('fruit');
            saveclass = saveclass ? saveclass : document.body.className;
            document.body.className = saveclass + ' ' + sel.value;
            setCookie('theme', cookieValue, 365);
        }

        function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays)
        {
           

            var today = new Date();
            var expire = new Date();

            if (nDays==null || nDays==0)
                nDays=1;

            expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
            document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString() +";path=/";
        }
        //......................read Cookie.............
         document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() 
        {
            var themeSelect = document.getElementById('fruit');
            var selectedTheme = readCookie('theme');

            themeSelect.value = selectedTheme;
            saveclass = saveclass ? saveclass : document.body.className;
            document.body.className = saveclass + ' ' + selectedTheme;
        });

        function readCookie(name) 
        {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) 
            {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }      
 </script>
```

Then you can Get the same option on other pages
[image]

**Yes , You are right . when I remove the days component from setCookie function.the cookie will only exist as long as the session does.**
[image]
[image]

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer. I do however want to clarify in regards to my question,  in order to use Model Binding my list is generated from an attached Page Model. Does eliminating Model Binding altogether and adopting a View Component in the _layout offer the best option for a Razor Pages solution?

Comment: as a follow up, could you confirm that if I remove the days component from your setCookie function that the cookie will only exist as long as the session does. This is important and one of the benefits of the ASP.Net HTTPCookie class

Comment: I write these hard-code just for testing convenience, you can use model binding to show these data too.I have changed my answer , you can see when I remove the days component from setCookie function that the cookie will only exist as long as the session does

Comment: HI @Xinran Shen, I am going to accept your answer as it does work for a hardcoded list. I would appreciate an explanation for you saying Model Binding will work. Under my understanding, the only way to get a dynamically filled select list in the _layout file is via View Components but I don't see any way of doing it via Model Binding.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer . In MVC , you can use`ViewData['xx']=new SelectList(xx)` in controller and `asp-items="xxx"` in view to achieve model binding . But , In Razor Page,It's very complicated to achieve model binding in `_layout`，So,If the code in _layout page does not change often, I recommend you to use hard-code directly.